# UITableView rotation issue

Tags: uitableview, ipad, scroll, rotation

I have `UIViewController` with a `UIView` with `UITableView` inside.

All works fine in Landscape mode but when the device is rotated to Portrait, bottom half of `UITableView` is not accessible (can't even select any row in the bottom half or make table scroll). All rows are displayed correctly.

I am re-framing and repositioning `UIView` and `UITableView` on rotation.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should adjust the autosizing in Interface Builder or in code.

I think the UITableView's height is still same with the value in Landscape mode after you rotate device to Portrait.

You can identify it by NSlog your UITableView's CGRect

```
NSlog(@"frame:%@",[NSStringFromCGRect(UITableView's CGRect)]);
```